# Query from external file in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a spring boot project and I want to make a query to keep in an external file (`.yaml`). I can use `@propertysource` and `@value` but there are many queries. Can I use `@propertysource` in every DAO? Is this a good design? Are there any alternatives for this?

Comment: why do you need to keep your query at `properties` file?

Comment: Now all the queries I kept in DAO, for better maintainability I want this to be in yml file

Answer (score 0):

1 ) Please put the all Queries in Properties file 
2 ) Give the properties file Location

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:queries.properties")
```

3 ) Injecting a property with the @Value annotation

```
@Value( "${Property which is exists in properties file.}" )
private String sampleQuery;
```

Refer [this](https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring)

Comment: But is this a good idea to have @PropertySource("classpath:queries.properties") in every DAO ?

Comment: Then go for xml configuration for the properties file setup.